# How do I use absolute path in a npm libarary

Tags: reactjs, npm, expo

I have a library that I want to use absolute path in it. it will be imported by other apps. e.g. react or expo. how can I enable absolute path in a such situations?

I tried to define babel config in the library root and using it in expo with no luck, any idea on this?

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            src: "./src"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm got your question right, I think you can use `path` library to resolve the current directory of your running code:

```
const path = require('path');
...
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
};
...
```

Comment: I  think this work in nodejs environment not in react or expo